# Resolution is very big

Tags: system-installation

i bad speak english , please help , i install elementary os and resolution is very very big , how to fix ? 
My monitor is a TV LG conected to pc in HDMI 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your `scaling-factor` to 1.

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1`